# Reading data from oracle using Flink

Tags: oracle, apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm trying to use Flink to work with Oracle. Just do a simple task copy data from table to a new one.

```
 EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.inStreamingMode();
        TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);

        tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE ExistedTable(\n" +
                "    quoteid  BIGINT,\n" +
                "    requestid      BIGINT,\n" +
                "    createddt DATE,\n" +           
                "    PRIMARY KEY (quoteid) NOT ENFORCED\n" +
                ") WITH (\n" +
                "    'connector' = 'jdbc',\n" +
                "    'url' = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:DBNAME',\n" +
                "    'table-name'    = 'TableName',\n" +
                "   'driver'     = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',\n" +
                "    'username'    = 'UserName',\n" +
                "    'password'    = 'Password'\n" +
                ")");

        tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE NewTable (\n" +
                "    quoteid  BIGINT,\n" +
                "    requestid      BIGINT,\n" +
                "    createddt DATE,\n" +           
                "    PRIMARY KEY (quoteid) NOT ENFORCED\n" +
                ") WITH (\n" +
                "    'connector' = 'jdbc',\n" +
                "    'url' = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:DBNAME',\n" +
                "    'table-name'    = 'NewTableName',\n" +
                "   'driver'     = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',\n" +
                "    'username'    = 'UserName',\n" +
                "    'password'    = 'Password'\n" +
                ")");

        Table data= tEnv.from("ExistedTable");
        data.executeInsert("NewTable");
```

When running I've got error

```
The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Unable to create a source for reading table 'default_catalog.default_database.xxx'.

Table options are:

'connector'='jdbc'
'driver'='oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
'password'='******'
'table-name'='xxx'
'url'='jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1521:xxx'
'username'='xxx'
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to create a source for reading table 'default_catalog.default_database.xxx'.
```

Is there any error in my sqlconnection. I couldn't found any example for working with oracle.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Flink are you using? Support for Oracle JDBC is available since Flink 1.15, which hasn't been released yet.

Comment: I use 1.14.3 (the stable version). I also try the lib from https://github.com/zengjinbo/flink-connector-oracle, however I faced new error: ```java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CHECK_LEAKED_CLASSLOADER```

Comment: There is no support for Oracle JDBC in Flink 1.14

Comment: got it, I though that they support oracle like mysql just change the connection string but it's not. So how should we do to use oracle as an input data, do we have some libs that does this work ? I've tried with the lib that I mentioned on previous comment but it did not works.

Comment: For the JDBC connector to work, you also need to include a driver as documented at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/ - The Oracle driver implementation is only done as of Flink 1.15

Comment: The only possible alternative I see is to use the Flink CDC connectors, which already have Oracle support. See https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors

Comment: I've just tried with the current snapshot of 1.15; However it seems still don't support Oralce yet. I got the exception: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Catalog for 'org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.dialect.oracle.OracleDialect@178270b2' is not supported yet.

Comment: OracleDialect has been added, as you can see in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14100 - The release candidate for Flink 1.15 should be out in the next couple of days, perhaps you could check it at that moment once more.

Comment: is there a way to establish this connection in Flink 1.13? please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71966243/flink-oracle-connection

Comment: New features aren't backported to older versions. The only possibility I can think of is to create your own custom Flink version with backports and run that yourself.