# Flink Oracle Connection

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis, flink-sql, pyflink

I am using AWS Kinesis Studio which supports **Flink 1.13**. I see that Flink 1.13 does not support Oracle connection.

Based on the documentation of version 1.13, it support **MySQL, PostgreSQL, Derby.**
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/

I am starting a new project and seeing this kind of issues make me reconsider my decision to go with **Flink** instead of **Spark**.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Fwiw, an Oracle driver has been added for Flink 1.15.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks for you answer. So, can I get it as there is no way to connect oracle for <1.15 version. (even with workarounds). That means AWS Kinesis cannot be used in this scenario since it supports up to v.1.13.
Apart from that Flink 1.15 is not released yet.

Comment: I’ve no idea how hard it might be to back port the driver to 1.13, or if KDA supports custom connectors or drivers. 1.15 will probably be released in about a week.